# How to get Last Five Days Dates in PST TimeZone and store it in a List<String> in java ? Time Part is not needed

Tags: java

Need to get last five days Dates and store it in a List. The DATE_FORMAT being **MM/dd/yyyy**.

Comment: Last five days? Relative to what?

Comment: RELATIVE TO CURRENT DATE

Answer (score 0):

You need minus miliseconds of days from current dates milisecond. Here is a sample example.

```java
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;

    class Dt {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws 
        Exception {
        long onedaymilisec=1*24*60*60*1000;
        Date d=new Date();
        ArrayList <String> al=new ArrayList<>();
        long curdatemilisec=d.getTime();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
          long prevdaymilisec = curdatemilisec - (i*onedaymilisec);
          Date pd =new Date(prevdaymilisec);
          DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");  
          df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
          String dfs=df.format(pd);
         al.add(dfs);
       }
       System.out.println(al);
    }
  }
```